# Almalinux SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/pki/tls/certs/certfiscme.crt' does not exist or is empty

Tags: https, openssl, almalinux

i have a problem with configure the certificate in Almalinux v8
this output when i run this command  `sudo systemctl restart httpd`

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

and this output win run this command: `journalctl -xe`

```
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
Jun 18 02:33:07 localhost.localdomain httpd[1679]: [Sun Jun 18 02:33:07.880635 2023] [so:warn] [pid 1679] AH01574: module rewrite_module is already loaded, skipping
Jun 18 02:33:07 localhost.localdomain httpd[1679]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 85 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
Jun 18 02:33:07 localhost.localdomain httpd[1679]: SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/pki/tls/certs/new.scme.edu.ps.crt' does not exist or is empty
Jun 18 02:33:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 18 02:33:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
```

i am trying to configure cert for https, i am make all configuration an contact support to solve the above problem

Comment: Looks like `/etc/pki/tls/certs/new.scme.edu.ps.crt` is not available at mentioned part or cert permission is different.